# Thermal History: Electron-Positron Annihilation

Tags: cosmology

At the moment I am studying for my cosmology exam and I am having a problem understanding the following from [Baumann's comsology lecture notes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y9bj9lzu2h0od9/LecturesNotesV2.pdf?dl=0):

> Shortly after the neutrinos decouple, the temperature drops below the electron mass and electron-positron annihilation occurs [...] (p.52).

I would have guessed that $T=2m_e$ is the temperature at which the reaction $\gamma\gamma\rightarrow e^+e^-$ is energetically disfavoured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget the temperature is a statistical variable, a type of average. This means that even at 1Mev temperature of the universe there are many particles with much higher energy than twice the electron mass. Decoupling has to do with the small  probability of interaction between the particles taking part in the universe at that time.

[Look at the model  deriving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_decoupling#Derivation_of_decoupling_time)  the decoupling of neutrinos time. It seems that the main interaction of the neutrinos before their decoupling is with electrons and positrons. Once the neutrinos do not have enough energy to scatter off electrons and positrons, (low probability, the probability of neutrino scattering goes up with energy) the annihilation of electrons on positrons can go unhindered by the weak interaction. So the two statements in your question  are not causal in the energy available, but in the competing processes of possible interactions.